# Arbitrage bot strange behaviour

Tags: solidity

I am looking at an arbitrage bot on BSC and I have noticed something that I quite can't explain. I've seen that every time the bot does a successful trade, various failing transactions with the same input data follow. [image]

Can this be because the bot streams the same transaction to different nodes, in order to increase its likelihood  of having the transaction included in the following block? If someone knows the reason, please explain, thanks!

Comment: Are the transactions from the same address? If there are more than one bot then it is likely they will send competing transactions, but for one bot it doesn't make much sense, but without the transaction details it is just a guess.